# Getting last or return a default value in a Seq[Either[A, B]]

Tags: scala

```
val y: Seq[Either[String, Int]]

case class Response(value: String)

val notFound = Response("Not Found")
val found    = Response("Found")

val response: Response = y.lastOption
    .map(_.fold(_ => notFound, _ => found))
    .getOrElse(notFound)
```

I am getting a list of Eithers. I want to get the last `Either` in the list. I then want to get `Right`value. If the list is empty or the Either is  `Left`, I want to return a default value. The code does this but can this be done more elegantly and clearer in Scala with perhaps cats? I don't use scalaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `map()` - `fold()` - `getOrElse()`, you could just use two `fold()` calls.

```
val response = Response(y.lastOption
                         .fold("Not Found")(_.fold(_=>"Not Found", _=>"Found")))
```

Or you could turn it into a single `Option` with just one `fold()`.

```
val response = Response(y.lastOption
                         .flatMap(_.toOption)
                         .fold("Not Found")(_ => "Found"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without folds, effectively using a `filter` instead:

```
l.lastOption.filter(_.isRight).map(_ => found).getOrElse(notFound)
```

I think it is a bit easier to read because every transformation is a single-function argument (as opposed to fold).

I found that `Option.filter` is a not-so-often used trick that can save what is effectively a conditional transformation in cases like that.